# Linguistics and ChatGPT

Tags: psycholinguistics, generative-grammar, neurolinguistics, language-generation

To which (neuro-, psycho- or general) linguistic models and theories of human language recognition and production does ChatGPT (GANs) come closest?

Or why isn't this a valid question?

Comment: I am sorry your question has been received with such hostility. It is a perfectly natural and understandable question for someone who is not from the field, but some people here tend to be quite agressive. I am in no possition to answer with authority, but I would suggest to look up things like n-gram models, syntactic tables and the field of natural language processing, among others. Incidentally, ChatGPT itself can give you good indications of what to look up about this subject.

Comment: I think you need to show some research and not ask such a broad, open-ended-type question. I think that's why you're getting dnvtes,

Answer (score 1):

The parrot can actually answer the question:

> As an AI language model, ChatGPT is primarily based on natural
> language processing (NLP) techniques that are derived from a variety
> of linguistic models and theories. Specifically, ChatGPT is built upon
> neural network architectures such as transformers, which are trained
> on large amounts of textual data to understand patterns and
> relationships within language.
>
> In terms of linguistic models and theories, ChatGPT does not align
> strictly with any specific framework, as its approach is data-driven
> and based on statistical learning rather than following a pre-defined
> linguistic theory. However, some of the concepts and techniques used
> in ChatGPT may be related to cognitive linguistic models and theories,
> which emphasize the role of mental structures and cognitive processes
> in language comprehension and production.
>
> Overall, ChatGPT's approach to language processing is grounded in
> machine learning and computational linguistics, which use mathematical
> and statistical methods to model language behavior and learn from
> data.

Focus on the various hedges like "may", and the blanket disclaimer about "a variety" (this is a common response that it gives when you ask about the sources of its "knowledge").